# What is the difference between はみ出す and はみ出る?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, transitivity

They are both intransitive:

> シャツがズボンから**はみ出しています**よ。
>   Your shirt is coming out of your pants.
>
> 足が 線から**はみ出ています**。
>   Your foot is over the line.

Comment: I was always taught that there was no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two verbs are almost the same. I checked the first 100 examples of "はみ出" on BCCWJ, and はみ出す and はみ出る were interchangeable **except**:

- はみ出る is less commonly used in the form of bare masu-stem, はみ出 (either as a noun or a replacement of te-form to continue a sentence). Although one-character masu-stems (見【み】, 来【き】, 寝【ね】) are less common before a comma in general.

  > ここのはみ出し【だし】部分が気になる。: OK
  > ここのはみ出【で】部分が気になる。: Less common
  >
  > シャツがはみ出し【だし】、だらしない恰好になっている。: OK
  > シャツがはみ出【で】、だらしない恰好になっている。: Less common
- はみ出し also has a meaning of "misfit", "outlaw", etc (はみ出し者, はみ出し野郎, ...). In this sense, はみ出者 is not wrong but less common for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The 大辞林 dictionary says they are the same:

https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%BF%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B